# Yesterday's date (validation)

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with my code. So, I want to create a validation for my dates. For example, today we are on `2020-05-31`, if the user enters a previous date to today, for example -> `2020-05-30`.

I should to get an error message.

My problem is that my error message isn't display.

Do have you an idea please?

I would like to stay faithful my code please. (I am beginner)

Thank you for your help and your time.

```js
function validation()
{
    const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;

    if(!date_start){
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Empty ! ";
        return false;
    }

    const inputDate = new Date(date_start).getDate();
    const today = new Date().getDate();

    if (inputDate < today || !inputDate.valueOf()) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
        return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
  <br>
  <label>Date start : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" placeholder="2020-05-28">
  <br>
  <span id="date_startError"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work within the same month. But don't call `getDate()`! That returns the day of the month. You'll be comparing 31 to to the day of the month entered and ignoring the month and year. Just compare the date objects directly without calling `.getDate()` on them.

Comment: And your code is missing a closing curly bracket (at the end of the last `if` statement)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me if you just append a "}" at the end. You always need a opening and closing curly bracket for functions (not only functions, actually everything that uses them) in your code, otherwise you get errors like these. I recommend vs-code as a code editor, so you can see if you wrote valid js or not.
*The function should look like this:*

```
function validation() {
        const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;

        if (!date_start) {
            document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Empty ! ";
            return false;
        }

        const inputDate = new Date(date_start).getDate();
        const today = new Date().getDate();

        if (inputDate < today || !inputDate.valueOf()) {
            document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
            return false;
        }
}
```

```js
function validation()
{
    const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;

    if(!date_start){
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Empty ! ";
        return false;
    }

    const inputDate = new Date(date_start).getDate();
    const today = new Date().getDate();

    if (inputDate < today || !inputDate.valueOf()) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
        return false;
}
} // <-----
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
  <br>
  <label>Date start : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" placeholder="2020-05-28">
  <br>
  <span id="date_startError"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a curly brace "}" for it to work, however the form will be submitted before you will be able to see the error message so to prevent that you will have to adjust your code and use `e.preventDefault`,
also consider consider comparing your dates differently because 
lets assume tomorrow 1st of June the user enter the date of today, your function will compare the 1st June < 30 of October and so it will break the logic of what you are trying to achieve so perhaps try to use milliseconds